# Programatically determine if an script is being executed on laptop or desktop?

Tags: linux, shell-script

Is there any reliable way to determine (programmatically) from within a bash script if it is being executed on a laptop or a desktop computer?

I could obviously just prompt the user to ask them, but that is pretty clunky.

Comment: I'd say why you need to know?  Are you worried about battery life

Comment: The script is doing some system setup for the user, and part of that is configuring some power saving settings if the device is a laptop.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Looking at whether or not the system has a battery is not reliable - a UPS connected to the system (not just for power, but over USB as well for automatic shutdown and battery monitoring) may show up as a battery.

There is a nice reliable way however:

```
dmidecode --string chassis-type
```

On a laptop, this will return one of "Laptop", "Notebook" "Portable", or "Sub Notebook" (depending on what the manufacturer coded into the BIOS).  There is a full list of possible values at "[Identifying the Chassis Type of a Computer](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee156537.aspx)" in the Windows 2000 Scripting Guide - don't worry about it being a Microsoft TechNet page, this is not OS specific.

dmidecode can also get information about the hardware manufacturer, system serial number (sometimes), etc.

Comment: I have a UPS controlled via USB for automatic shutdown and battery monitoring with [Network UPS Tool](http://www.networkupstools.org/). It is does _not_ show up as a "battery" on the Desktop. What configuration are you using that under which a UPS appears in `/sys/module/battery`?

Comment: This works better than the /sys/module/battery method: My two Ubuntu 14.04 desktops answer "Desktop" and "Low Profile Desktop", respectively, and the one with CentOS 6.5 says "Unknown". The one with CentOS 5.3 doesn't recognize the keyword "chassis-type". The Laptop I tried it on says "Notebook". But it's a drawback that you need root access.

Comment: I really like this answer!

Comment: +1 for distribution independence.  I tested it successfully on several machines.  The only machine on which dmidecode gave a less than helpful answer was an Aspire netbook returned a chassis type of `Other`.

Comment: this answer requires sudo, so is not viable for things like `.bashrc` files. Querying the contents of `/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type`, which is just a single number, is much better (as another answer below pointed out).

Answer (score 13):

To avoid using sudo, you can read the contents of `/sys/class/dmi/id/chassis_type`, which will return the decimal value of the chassis type.

The meaning of the values can be seen in official documentation PDFs available at https://www.dmtf.org/standards/SMBIOS

The following table includes the information for smbios specification version 3.5.0 (22 Sep 2021).

| Decimal value | Hex value | Meaning |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 01h | Other |
| 2 | 02h | Unknown |
| 3 | 03h | Desktop |
| 4 | 04h | Low Profile Desktop |
| 5 | 05h | Pizza Box |
| 6 | 06h | Mini Tower |
| 7 | 07h | Tower |
| 8 | 08h | Portable |
| 9 | 09h | Laptop |
| 10 | 0Ah | Notebook |
| 11 | 0Bh | Hand Held |
| 12 | 0Ch | Docking Station |
| 13 | 0Dh | All in One |
| 14 | 0Eh | Sub Notebook |
| 15 | 0Fh | Space-saving |
| 16 | 10h | Lunch Box |
| 17 | 11h | Main Server Chassis |
| 18 | 12h | Expansion Chassis |
| 19 | 13h | SubChassis |
| 20 | 14h | Bus Expansion Chassis |
| 21 | 15h | Peripheral Chassis |
| 22 | 16h | RAID Chassis |
| 23 | 17h | Rack Mount Chassis |
| 24 | 18h | Sealed-case PC |
| 25 | 19h | Multi-system chassis When this value is specified by an SMBIOS implementation, the physical chassis associated with this structure supports multiple, independently reporting physical systems—regardless of the chassis' current configuration. Systems in the same physical chassis are required to report the same value in this structure's Serial Number field. For a chassis that may also be configured as either a single system or multiple physical systems, the multi-system chassis value is reported even if the chassis is currently configured as a single system. This allows management applications to recognize the multi-system potential of the chassis. |
| 26 | 1Ah | Compact PCI |
| 27 | 1Bh | Advanced TCA |
| 28 | 1Ch | Blade An SMBIOS implementation for a Blade would contain a Type 3 Chassis structure for the individual Blade system as well as one for the Blade Enclosure that completes the Blade system. |
| 29 | 1Dh | Blade Enclosure A Blade Enclosure is a specialized chassis that contains a set of Blades. It provides much of the non-core Computing infrastructure for a set of Blades (power, cooling, networking, and so on). A Blade Enclosure may itself reside inside a Rack or be a standalone chassis. |
| 30 | 1Eh | Tablet |
| 31 | 1Fh | Convertible |
| 32 | 20h | Detachable |
| 33 | 21h | IoT Gateway |
| 34 | 22h | Embedded PC |
| 35 | 23h | Mini PC |
| 36 | 24h | Stick PC |

Comment: Source for the table? And is 'lunch box' a joke?!

Comment: @OJFord I do not have a citation at this time. As far as 'lunchbox', it is a nickname give to a form factor. I've worked with a few lunchboxes and pizzaboxes before. While this link may not last years, you can see some very modern lunchbox computers http://www.theportablepc.com/portable-pc.html

Comment: Grant's answer contains a citation from microsoft: https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/tn-archive/ee156537(v=technet.10)

Comment: Thanks! Now I want one... But I suspect my wallet doesn't.

Comment: This was the only solution that worked for me without needing to sudo. The battery-based solutions either said my ubuntu desktop was a laptop, or said my debian laptop was a desktop.

Comment: Pizza box? How would it even detect that it's running in a pizza box?

Comment: That source (microsoft page linked above) is outdated, as noted on it, and does not contain all values from specification. The official source is here: https://www.dmtf.org/standards/smbios

Comment: I have edited the answer to include all current values.

Answer (score 10):

#### Debian Solution:

To find whether a machine running Debian is a laptop, try:

```
[ -d /sys/module/battery ] && echo "Yes it's a laptop"
```

This approach does not require `root` privileges.

On other distributions, however, this directory seems to exist, at least in skeleton form, regardless of whether or not there is a battery.  From the comments (below), these distributions include CentOS, Ubuntu, and the Ubuntu-derived distribution of Linux Mint.

#### More General Solution

Although it does not work on my Debian systems, [the solution proposed by Alex](/sys/module/battery/initstate) reportedly works on Ubuntu & CentOS.  Thus suggests, for greater generality, a possible combined solution:

```
[ -f /sys/module/battery/initstate ] || [ -d /proc/acpi/battery/BAT0 ] && echo "Yes it's a laptop"
```

This approach does not require `root` privileges.

#### More Details

On a Debian system with an actual battery, the `/sys/module/battery` directory contains many files.  One such file is `/sys/module/battery/initstate` which contains the text `live`.  On Ubuntu, however, these files do not exist even on actual laptops.  Thus, it appears that the presence of the file `/sys/module/battery/initstate` can be used to test for a laptop running Debian.

On Debian systems that I tested, by contrast, the `/proc/acpi/battery` directory did not exist.

Comment: Isn't it possible that the second command could still return true in the case of a desktop with a UPS?

Comment: @PseudoPsyche I just tested it on a desktop with a UPS and it returned false (not a laptop).

Comment: Doesn't a UPS go between the wall socket and a computer power socket?

Comment: What is that first command doing there?

Comment: @AndreKR It was there because the wording of the question was originally ambiguous.

Comment: Apparently my 4U IBM server with an APC SmartUPS plugged in over USB is a laptop.  I certainly wouldn't want that thing on my lap all day!  (ie, if it has a UPS plugged in and configured for shutdown/monitoring, that directory will exist)

Comment: What happens when a laptop doesn't have a battery installed?

Comment: This failed on my home desktop, which is a standard Mint install. Alex's answer below worked fine, on the other hand. It seems like a robust solution ought to check whether the battery hardware is actually physically present instead of merely checking for the existence of a battery management module, which may just happen to have been installed by default.

Comment: This does not seem to be very reliable. I just tried this on four different desktop computers: two with Ubuntu 14.04, one with CentOS 5.2, and one with CentOS 6.5. None of them has a battery or a UPS. Still, all four of them had /sys/module/battery.

Comment: This doesn't work sadly. I tried it on my desktop just now and got "Yes it's a laptop". `dmidecode --string chassis-type` on the other hand did report "Desktop"

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy I tested with Ubuntu-14.04 (live) and revised the answer.  If you have the time and interest, it would be appreciated if you would check the revised answer on your systems.

Comment: +1 because it doesnt require root privileges.  If you have root, dmidecode is probably the more reliable answer, but without it the revisted version her is useful.

Comment: @John1024: It still doesn't work for me. The directory is not fully populated on the four desktops, so the file /sys/module/battery/initstate doesn't exist, but unfortunately the directory isn't populated on the laptop either (a Lenovo ThinkPad E330 with Ubuntu 14.04). So it still doesn't work for me. The /proc method works on all five machines, though.

Comment: @ThomasPadron-McCarthy Thanks much for the results:  I've completely rewritten the answer.  The `/proc` method does _not_ work on either of the Debian laptops that I tested.

Answer (score 8):

I'd check if the computer has a battery installed. And the following is one way to test:

```
if [ -d /proc/acpi/battery/BAT* ]; then
  echo has a battery
fi
```

Comment: This method gave the correct answer on all five computers I tried it on: two desktops with Ubuntu 14.04, one desktop with CentOS 5.3, one desktop with CentOS 6.5, and one laptop with Ubuntu 14.04. Also, it doesn't require root access. Of the three methods in the answers, my tests indicate that this may, tentatively, be the best one.

Comment: This works for me.

Comment: This did not work on the two Debian laptops that I tested but __+1__ for working on a variety of other important distributions.

Comment: Doesn't work for me (Toshiba Notebook), because my battery is named BAT1. I don't know how many other possible names there might be.

Comment: @Joe Change `BAT0` to `BAT*` -- it should detect all variations.

Comment: @Alex - Yes. I just wanted to point out that the hard coded BAT0 wasn't reliable. You might want to edit this into your answer.

Comment: This doesn't work on Manjaro

Comment: this did not work on my debian laptops.

Answer (score 2):

Another solution that does not require sudo:

```
hostnamectl status | grep Chassis | cut -f2 -d ":" | tr -d ' '
```

Will output `laptop` or `desktop`.

Answer (score 1):

If checking for battery existence is good enough, you can use this shell function:

```
# Checks whether system is a laptop.
#
# @returns {bool}   true if system is a laptop.
function is_laptop() {
    local d
    for d in /sys/class/power_supply /proc/acpi/battery; do
        [[ -d "$d" ]] && find $d -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name 'BAT*' -print0 -quit 2>/dev/null | grep -q . && return 0
    done

    # note we're checking /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status for WSL
    for d in /sys/class/power_supply/battery/status /sys/module/battery/initstate; do
        [[ -f "$d" ]] && return 0
    done

    return 1
}
```

Have been using this on Debian for years.
Note this works also for Debian running in WSL or virtualbox.

*Edit: generalized from other answers in this thread to catch more cases.*